# Azure DNS Zone name servers updated to Domain registrar but unknown host even after 4-5 hours

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

How to setup root domain ( example.com ) to point to Azure DNS zone? I am not sure whether it is because of propagation lag, but if I try to access example.com ( for example here ), it gives me unknown host.

**My Steps**:

1. Created the Azure DNS Zone for the example.com.
2. Created the www.example.com DNS zone.
3. Delegated subdomain to Azure DNS zone created in step #1 above for www Name server record.
4. Logged in to domain registrar and updated the 4 name servers of step 1 DNS Zone name servers as shared by portal.azure.com.

**Note:** It is 4-5 hours now and even now, accessing example.com ( dummy ) gives me unknown host. I tried the following as well and details are as below:-

a. **Ping**

1. List item

   example.com => Gives following:
   C:\Users\GURU>ping example.com
   Ping request could not find host example.com. Please check the name and try again.

b. **Telnet** example.com on port 13782 but Couldntfind .. message.

c. **nslookup** gives below:

> C:\Users\GURU>nslookup
>   DNS request timed out.
>       timeout was 2 seconds.
>   Default Server:  UnKnown
>   Address:  fd00::1
>
> set querytype=soa
>   example.com
>   Server:  UnKnown
>   Address:  fd00::1
>   DNS request timed out.

**But, I find the DIG and intoDNS showing all good**, properly set the nameservers on registrar panel. I am not sure if I am missing anything.

Using DIG tool, 
https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames={changed_abc.com}&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=

> changed_me.com.   299 IN  SOA ns1-05.azure-dns.com. azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com. 1 3600 300 2419200 300

Hoping I did all right, and validating on anything I could have missed. Please suggest , if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, It appears that www.saffrongeek.com gets properly routed to Parent DNS zone on Azure from the Domain registrar recorded settings for Name servers. But was not getting delegated to child DNS zone.

On top of the settings in this picture, I ***added a A @ record at Azure Child DNS zone pointing to IP***.Now both root domain, saffrongeek.com and www subdomain works.

[image: Existing setting]

Answer (score 1):

The Apex domain now works perfectly following the cmdlets with corrections as recommended added. Ref: [Azure DNS - Domains Not Being Found By Public Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683328/azure-dns-domains-not-being-found-by-public-internet)

I had my registrar with a A record pointing to webapp IP, and nameservers to that of azure DNS zone for example.com in place of default registrars.

But, www.example.com gives me unknown host but i checked each step as recommended still but not able to make out what I am missing during setup.

[image: My current configuration summary]

**www.saffrongeek.com@8.8.4.4 (Default):**

> www.saffrongeek.com.    9   IN  CNAME   saffrongeek.com.
>
> saffrongeek.com.    59  IN  A   191.236.59.67

**saffrongeek.com@8.8.4.4 (Default):**

> saffrongeek.com.    59  IN  A   191.236.59.67

Comment: Any suggestions on what I could be missing that www subdomain is giving me unknown host?

Comment: Hope this looks correct. saffrongeek.com@8.8.4.4 (Default):
saffrongeek.com. 59 IN A 191.236.59.67

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have already found the answer to your issue, given this question is very old. I was having same issue and I found your post here helpful.

Coming to your issue that www.example.com is getting unknown host, I created an A record and pointed that to the VM public IP address. I figured we can set Load Balancer IP address as well here.

I created 2 A records

1) www.example.com: set www in name field when creating A record.
2) example.com: leave name field blank when creating A record